# Populate DataGridView from a List

Tags: c#

I have a list of string, int and object. I need to populate a datagridview with those values, but when I tried to populate the object value doesn't work.

This is my declaration for the class:

```
public int ClientAddressId { get; set; }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public CityModel City { get; set; }
    public CountyModel County { get; set; }
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    public string StreetNo { get; set; }
```

This is my declaration for the method that return a list:

```
public BindingList<ClientAddressModel> GetClientAddressBi(int clientId)
    {
        DAClientAddress dac = new DAClientAddress();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = dac.GetClientAddress(clientId);
    

        BindingList<ClientAddressModel> list = new BindingList<ClientAddressModel>();          
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            ClientAddressModel address = new ClientAddressModel();
            address.ClientAddressId = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["ClientAddressId"].ToString());
            address.ClientId = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["ClientId"].ToString());
            address.City = new CityModel
            {
                CityId = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["CityId"].ToString()),
                CityName = dt.Rows[i]["CityName"].ToString()
            };
            address.County = new CountyModel{
                CountyId = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["CountyId"].ToString()),
                CountyName = dt.Rows[i]["CountyName"].ToString()
            };                  
            address.StreetName = dt.Rows[i]["StreetName"].ToString();
            address.StreetNo = dt.Rows[i]["StreetNo"].ToString();

            list.Add(address);                

        }
```

This is where I suppose to populate datagrid view

```
BLClientAddress blca = new BLClientAddress();
        BindingList<ClientAddressModel> list = blca.GetClientAddressBi(PartnerId );
        dataGridClientAddress.DataSource = list;
```

That is what my app return

[image]

Comment: It looks like it populated correctly but when you write CityName = dt.Rows[i]["CityName"].ToString() it returns the name of the Object not the actual value so that part is probably confusing you... remove ToString() and see if you get the actual value

Comment: Why don't you create a _ClientAddressViewModel_ class with the properties that you want to display in the grid?

Comment: Or you want to add an override for the ToString() method in the class County and City and return what you want to show in the columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simple scenario like this one I suggest to simply add an override for the ToString method inside the classes CityModel and CountyModel

```
public class CityModel
{
   public int CityId { get; set; }
   public string CityName { get; set; }
   public override string ToString()
   {
       return CityName;
   }
}
public class CountyModel
{
   public int CountyId { get; set; }
   public string CountyName { get; set; }
   public override string ToString()
   {
       return CountyName;
   }
}
```

The DataGridViewTextBoxColumn calls the ToString() on the County and City properties to get the value to display. If you don't override that method you get the object's name. With the override you get what you decide to return from that method.